# hyperlink an \item and \ref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lists, enumitem

I have a custom environment which is just an `enumerate` with the `\item` written for me. I would like the enumeration label to be a hyperlink- in the MWE below, it simply links to a page at the end of the document.

When referencing the environment using `\ref` the printed version will look fine. However, you'll notice that the hyperlink created  by `\ref{testref}` goes to the same link that the enumeration label goes to, and not to the environment that it references.

What needs to be changed to get the hyperlinks to behave as expected?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}     % sample text
\usepackage{enumitem}   % enumerations
\usepackage{hyperref}   % hyperlinks        

\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{subproblem}
\newenvironment{problem}{\setcounter{subproblem}{0}\refstepcounter{problem}{\bfseries Problem \theproblem}}{}
\newenvironment{subproblem}{%
    \stepcounter{subproblem}%
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\hyperlink{newpage}{\theproblem.\thesubproblem},leftmargin=*]
     \item}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
 \begin{subproblem}
  \lipsum[1]
 \end{subproblem}
 \begin{subproblem}\label{testref}
  \lipsum[1]
 \end{subproblem}
\end{problem}

Test reference: \ref{testref}

\begin{problem}
 \begin{subproblem}
  \lipsum[1]
 \end{subproblem}
 \begin{subproblem}
  \lipsum[1]
 \end{subproblem}
\end{problem}

\newpage

\hypertarget{newpage}{We'll link to this}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`?

Comment: @Mico Tried that already, no difference. I'm not convinced that the environment is setup correctly- I think it may be more appropriate to use the `resume` feature from `enumitem`, but I haven't been able to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some corrections incorporated in your MWE. They include:

- Using a master counter to reset your `subproblem` at every increment or `problem`:

  ```
  \newcounter{subproblem}[problem]
  ```

  This removed the requirement for setting the `subproblem` counter to `0` every time (`\setcounter{subproblem}{0}`) at the start of the `problem` environment.
- Adding a referenced stepping of the subproblem counter using

  ```
  \refstepcounter{subproblem}
  ```
- Explicitly stating the reference included with the `enumerate` environment, even though it is similar to the `label` to avoid the `label` from being considered the same as the `ref`. This corrected the incorrect referencing to elements:

  ```
  \begin{enumerate}%
    [label=\protect\hyperlink{newpage}{\theproblem.\thesubproblem},% label
     ref=\theproblem.\thesubproblem,% reference
     leftmargin=*]% left margin
  ```

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}     % sample text
\usepackage{enumitem}   % enumerations
\usepackage{hyperref}   % hyperlinks        

\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{subproblem}[problem]
\newenvironment{problem}{\refstepcounter{problem}{\bfseries Problem~\theproblem}}{}
\newenvironment{subproblem}{%
    \refstepcounter{subproblem}%
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\hyperlink{newpage}{\theproblem.\thesubproblem},ref=\theproblem.\thesubproblem,leftmargin=*]
     \item}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
 \begin{subproblem}
  \lipsum[1]
 \end{subproblem}
 \begin{subproblem}\label{testref}
  \lipsum[1]
 \end{subproblem}
\end{problem}

Test reference: \ref{testref}

\begin{problem}
 \begin{subproblem}
  \lipsum[1]
 \end{subproblem}
 \begin{subproblem}
  \lipsum[1]
 \end{subproblem}
\end{problem}

\newpage

\hypertarget{newpage}{We'll link to this}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant! As always, thanks not only for the answer, but for the detailed explanation.